# Mockito mocking callback interface

Tags: mockito

I have very basic service with method `post` that updates it's progress via callback interface.

```
public class HttpPostService {
    public interface UploadingProgressListener {
        void onProgress(int progress);
    }

    public int post(InputStream body, UploadingProgressListener listener)
    {
         // shortened for brevity
         // read inputstream and writes bytes to HttpURLConnection outputstream
         // read inputstream in loop notify listener about progress
         listener.onProgress(percentage);
    }
}
```

I would like to test this class with Mockito, basically mock `UploadingProgressListener` and then check if it was called n-times with correct percentage arguments.

```
@Test
public void testPostFileProgressListener() throws IOException {
    UploadingProgressListener mockListener = mock(UploadingProgressListener.class);

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream();
    service.postFile(inputStream, mockListener);
    verify(mockListener, times(5)).onProgress(100);
}
```

However when I run test it says it was only invoked one time, but when I debug it listener was called 5 times.

I know there is concept of Answers and ArgumentCaptors, but I thought at least counting how many times mock was called would be correct. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would the callback be called 5 times with 100 as argument? Shouldn't it be called once with 20, then once with 40, then once with 60, then once with 80, then once with 100 (for example)?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed want to check that there was an ordered sequence of 5 calls, with 20, 40, 60, 80 and 100 as argument, you just need

```
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockListener);
    inOrder.verify(mockListener).onProgress(20);
    inOrder.verify(mockListener).onProgress(40);
    inOrder.verify(mockListener).onProgress(60);
    inOrder.verify(mockListener).onProgress(80);
    inOrder.verify(mockListener).onProgress(100);
```

If you just want to check that the listener has been called 5 times, without caring about the arguments, then just use

```
    verify(mockListener, times(5)).onProgress(anyInt());
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Just one question. Why verify(mockListener, times(5)).onProgress(100); says it was executed only 1 time (ignoring the fact onProgress(100) is wrong

Comment: The error message should tell you that: it was invoked once with 100. The 4 other times were invoked with 20, 40, 60 and 80